# Axios browser support

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios, browser-support

My situation is that I'm building a react app and I don't want to use jquery anymore. So I'm planning to use Axios or Fetch. After researching about those, I get that Axios has much more powerful API then fetch. But the thing is I don't know what is the browser support for it. Does it support all browsers with es2015?

Comment: Did you have a look [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#browser-support)?

Comment: Does it mean that it supports all versions until the latest?

Comment: No it doesn't specify minimum versions. But we could try figuring it out. Their [first release](https://github.com/axios/axios/tree/v0.1.0) is dated Aug 10, 2014. And the README of that release states that it supported >=IE8, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. By looking at [this chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Timeline_of_web_browsers.svg) you should be able to find the lower bound. Of course, this assumes that they were not dropping support of older browser versions along the way. it appears they are dropping older IE versions IE 8,9,10.

Comment: When it comes to evergreen browsers the convention is to only state support and assume everyone is going to be using the latest version so if it states support for Chrome you can assume it supports the version of Chrome that everyone will be using. IE is the only exception and currently support is for IE 11

Answer (score 1):

[axios browser support](https://github.com/axios/axios) as of the latest version today, [version 0.19.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios/v/0.19.2):

[image]